# how to open pdf, ppt, word, etc files in android?

Tags: java, android, pdf, file-handling, decoding

I am downloading certain types of files in my app (pdf, ppt, doc, mp4, etc). Right now I am launching these files in their default applications in the device.
Is there any way that I might open these inside my own app?

I have explored other similar questions, I am currently trying out apache poi api for my purpose but I am not sure it will work on all types of files.

I want to know if I have to decode and render these formats in my own applications, what kind of an effort will that take?
And also, since I don't know where to start, is there reference available from which I could get help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is the concept of Android to have individual applications for each type of file and to open them by Intent as you are doing. As I did not find a reasonable way to do what you want to do, I follow the concept and do not implement this functionality separately.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks, if I just wanted to read a pdf file, what would be the basic steps involved to render it?